# Sql server suddenly stopped recognizing my new columns

Tags: stored-procedures, intellisense, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a `stored procedure` in `SQL SERVER 2012`.

Suddenly, my stored procedure can't compile.

it says `invalid column name` on every column I try to add.

But I can run queries and the columns are there

```
SELECT FirstName FROM dbo.Contacts
```

Also, I made no change to the code.

- I tried to reboot
- I recreated the columns
- I refreshed the `intelliSense` cache

No luck...

here's a part of the code

```
DECLARE curContact Cursor

FOR SELECT dbo.Contacts.ContactID, dbo.Contacts.FirstName, dbo.Contacts.MiddleName, dbo.Contacts.LastName, dbo.Contacts.ContactName FROM dbo.Contacts
FOR UPDATE OF  dbo.Contacts.FirstName, dbo.Contacts.MiddleName, dbo.Contacts.LastName
OPEN curContact
```

here's the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts](
    [ContactID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MillID] [int] NULL,
    [ClientID] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [Gender] [bit] NULL,
    [ContactName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactTitle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactPhoneNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactPhoneExt] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactFaxNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ContactCellNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactPageNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactHomeNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactOtherNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Language] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [CalendarQuantityEnglish] [smallint] NULL,
    [CalendarQuantityFrench] [smallint] NULL,
    [CalendarKeepBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CalendarComment] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [OtherQuantityEnglish] [smallint] NULL,
    [OtherQuantityFrench] [smallint] NULL,
    [OtherKeepBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OtherComment] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Validated] [date] NULL,
    [ValidedByWho] [nvarchar](64) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Show your code. Does your stored procedure use the dbo. prefix in its name? Are the tables you're referencing properly prefixed as well?

Comment: Yes, I posted the code in my question

Comment: What is the purpose of this cursor? Which column gives the error? Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` script for the `dbo.Contacts` table? Are you sure your procedure is in the same database? (As an aside, you won't get an error from SQL Server when trying to compile the procedure if the IntelliSense cache hasn't been updated - that's not where SQL Server checks validity of objects / columns.)

Comment: FirstName, LastName, Middlename are the colums that give the error. I added them this morning with the sql server manager. There are even data in them and I can do select queries

Comment: Ok, so in addition to the table structure can you explain what "sql server manager" is? Do you mean Management Studio? Also are you running this query in Visual Studio? What is your connection string? Does it use `User Instance` and `AttachDbFilename`?

Comment: yes, I used the management studio to add the columns and to do the queries. And I use the windows authentication to connect to this database that is local on my desktop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to refresh SSMS Intellisense Cache (CTRL + SHIFT + R or Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache).

Comment: That should actually be the accepted answer because it solves the problem and is not just a workaround...